when doing an STL decomposition, is is possible to take the first derivative and get a confidence interval around it to test if different from zero?
when doing an STL decomposition, is is possible to take the first derivative and get a confidence interval around it to test if different from zero?
I know this can be done with GAMS as shown in this blog by Gavin Simpson.
https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/05/15/identifying-periods-of-change-with-gams/

Can this be done with an STL?

im not a time series expert and i dont know about the specifics of your method. I just want to comment that the methodology mentioned in your citation by Simpson of using finite differencing is general enough to be applied to any (continuously differentiable) predictor, which judging by your plot would include the one you are interested in.

What are you "taking the first derivative of" and what are you testing for difference from zero??  Indeed, are you sure you are asking about a confidence interval at all?  Maybe a prediction interval?

taking the first derivative of the trend component (as identified by the STL). I want to Test if the rate of change of the trend is non-zero.
